# How to use redux thunk function in typescripts?

Tags: typescript, react-redux, redux-thunk

I've tried to write a piece of thunk function using typescripts as below:

```js
export const fetchBooks = async(dispatch:BookDispatch, getState:()=>RootState) => {
    const initBooks = await GetBooks();
    dispatch(FetchAllBooks(initBooks));
}
```

When I invoked the above thunk function using the following code in the component, it occurred the following error even this error has not any effect on running.

```js
store.dispatch(fetchBooks);
```

Error message:

```js
Argument of type '(dispatch: BookDispatch, getState: () => RootState) => void' 
is not assignable to parameter of type 'BookActions'.
```

My question is how to fix this error message?